# How to replace multiples objects with differents rotations?

Tags: modeling

I have a jewel with multiples diamonds with differents rotations that i imported from rhino, sadly those diamonds have poor topology i want to replace them with another one with proper topology. If i link object data, they all lose their rotations and will be all straight.

i think if you open my file, it will be easier to understand.
https://blend-exchange.com/b/yAQ1rYJ6
I also tried to Align to transformation but i don't think i can do it 100 times for every jewels, if you know anything it will be a huge help even addon i don't mind

Comment: Hi :). You can do it manually rather easily. Just snap the origin point to the top vertex on each diamond. It will align itself properly to the diamond's orientation :). You do need to click ~100 times, but it's better than nothing :))

Comment: @jachymmichal yeah that is what i was thinking, maybe i'll find a way to do it fast in rhinoceros, because doing it this way is too time consuming

Comment: 100 pieces is still doable, you'll be done in ~15 minutes :)